# Dynamically passing GroupBy Key

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if I could dynamically pass the GroupBy Key. For example,

```
public interface ISampleType
{
}

public class SampleType1:ISampleType
{
}

public class SampleType2:ISampleType
{
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public int Property2{get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var list = new List<AnotherClass>();
    ISampleType sample = new SampleType1();

    var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Property1);
}
```

In above example, instead of Grouping by Property1, I would need to group by Property2 if ISample is of type SampleType2.I could do this with switch, but unfortunately its not an option for me since ISampleType implementations would increase with time.

I was wondering if I could introduce a property in ISampleType, that acts as Grouping Key. For example,

```
 Expression<Func<AnotherClass, TKey>> GroupingKey {get;}
```

Here is where I am kind of struck at, as am not quite aware how to passs 'AnotherClass.Property' when I implement the interface in SampleType2.

**Update**

```
if(sample is SampleType1)
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Property1);
else if(sample is SampleType2)
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Property2);
```

What would be the best way to implement this, (preferably avoiding Reflection, if at all possible) ?

**Update 02:**

One solution I do have is of course using reflection.

```
public interface ISampleType
{
   string GroupingKey{get;}
}

public class SampleType1:ISampleType
{
    public string GroupingKey => nameof(AnotherClass.Property1);
}

public class SampleType2:ISampleType
{
    public string GroupingKey => nameof(AnotherClass.Property2);
}
```

and then

```
var result = list.GroupBy(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(sample.GroupingKey).GetValue(c, null));
```

But I was wondering if this is possible without reflection

Comment: I could not understand the use case. If you pass statically sample type, why not write group by property by hand? I could not see generic structure here. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @EmreSavcı i have updated the code to make it the user case more clear (hopefully). I have more than handful of ISampleType Implementations, and depending on the 'sample' I would like to group by different keys. Since the ISampleType implementations could increase with time, I wanted to avoid switch/if ways.

Comment: And yes, sample is declared else where, not in the same function as shown above (which is more a simplified sample). So, method itself is not aware of the current value of Sample.

Comment: Sure the idea of inheritance is that you can vary the implementation on a per-class-that-implements-this-interface level, the value that is returned from a method or property that provides the grouping key? Your interface ISample has a .GroupingKey that your LINQ query uses, but in every subclass implementing ISample you make, GroupingKey returns some different value, some combination of the other properties? You say everything is unaware of sample1/2 but it needs making aware, this is the design element you have to overcome to use polymorphism here

Comment: @CaiusJard I have updated the code with a reflection based solution of what I would ideally like to have. I am sorry, but i couldn't entirely understand what you were directing me to. (btw, was that a misplaced ? or the whole thing was question for me )

Comment: It's a question to make you think.  You say AnotherClass should be grouped differently depending if ISample implementation is Sample1 or Sample2 so why not have ISample have an abstract method GetGroupingKeyFor(AnotherClass a) and then each concrete subclass implements the method differently, but your LINQ query always groups on isample.getGruupingKeyFor

Comment: What would be the return Type of GetGroupingKeyFor ? "Expression<Func<AnotherClass, TKey>>"  - If that's the case, how would say, SampleType1.GetGroupingKey return ? How would it be different from having the GroupingKey property as described in the question ? Extremely sorry, If am understanding your hint wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem, you can not use generic TKey type in non generic interface. To union all the types you would need to use object. It would imply boxing in some cases, but it should work.

```
public interface ISampleType
{
    Func<AnotherClass, object> GroupingKey { get; }
}

public class SampleType1 : ISampleType
{
    public Func<AnotherClass, object> GroupingKey => a => a.Property1;
}

public class SampleType2 : ISampleType
{
    public Func<AnotherClass, object> GroupingKey => a => a.Property2;
}

void Main()
{
    var list = new List<AnotherClass>();
    ISampleType sample = new SampleType1();

    var result = list.GroupBy(sample.GroupingKey);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine, but I would like to wait a little more to see if someone can do away with Boxing here. If there is no more answers, which can do away with Boxing by EOD, I will mark this answer